# get the innertext with in a html dom using vbscript in UFT

Tags: html, dom, vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to verify if TravelerID got created and showing up in the Add Traveler table.
[AddTraveler Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foAg7.png)

I was able to capture the webelement

[ObjectRepository of the AddTraveler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDVYP.png)
To capture the innertext I need to create DOM object first. Then I can use the methods of the DOM object.

This is how I am capturing the DOM object

```
resultsObj = Browser("Manufacturing Milpitas").Page("Manufacturing Milpitas").Frame("Results_AddTraveler").Object
```

Here is the tricky part.  I am not able to capture the inner HTML or any method of that DOM object.

The Method I have to use  is getElementById, but this webelement doesn’t have ID it only has class.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: to set an object reference in `VBScript`/`UFT`, you need to use the `Set` keyword, as in `Set resultsObj = ...`

Comment: Based on the two images you've shared, the object you have recorded in the object repository will not match the object in your image.  You have specified that for the object to be recognised, it must have an `innertext` value of 10300...86 where the object you are looking at shows a value of 10300...89

Answer (score 1):

To find innertext use the following code

```
Browser("Manufacturing Milpitas").Page("Manufacturing Milpitas").Frame("Results_AddTraveler").WebElement("WebTable").GetROProperty("innertext")
```

Comment: This is the error I am getting when I am doing that.


Cannot identify the object "WebTable" (of class WebElement).
Verify that this object's properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

Comment: This clearly indicates that UFT is unable to identify the object at runtime and the reason for that is : You are using innertext as the identification property in the object repository. You should use something else. Because its a value inside the table you can also add the Webtable Object in the object repository instead of webelement and use the GetCellData method to get the value from the table row and column. https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib~WebTable.html#GetCellData

Answer (score 0):

Your object in the object repository has the previous TravelerID under innertext property, so UFT is unable to identify the object every time a new TravelerID is generated.

You do not need to go with that object. Capture Webtable object and use GetCellData(Row,Column) method to get the value from "Traveler ID" column.

```
Msgbox Browser("Manufacturing Milpitas").Page("Manufacturing Milpitas").Frame("Results_AddTraveler").WebTable("WebTable").GetCellData(Row,Column)
'Here, Row = 2 and Column = 2
```

If you want to get the column number during run time, use the below approach -

```
Set ObjWebTable = Browser("Manufacturing Milpitas").Page("Manufacturing Milpitas").Frame("Results_AddTraveler").WebTable("WebTable")
iColumncount = ObjWebTable.Columncount(1)
For i=1 To iColumncount
    If ObjWebTable.GetCellData(1,i) = "Traveler ID" Then
        iColumnNumber = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Msgbox ObjWebTable.GetCellData(1,iColumnNumber)
Set ObjWebTable = Nothing
```

Comment: I got assigned to another project and didn't get time to try it out. but Thank you for answering. I will try that and let you know if it works.